# Set python object to variable

Tags: python, static

I've been trying out this code and am oblivious to why it does not work.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self=False
        print self #Prints false
print Foo() #Prints `<__main__.Foo object at 0x026B3970>`
```

I thought it might be that `self` is only a reference to the object but passing `self=[]` or `self=object` does not work either.

I know this approach is not exactly a good technique but I am wondering why it does not set the object to the specific value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't *ignore* the assignment. The assignment works just fine, you created a local name that points to False.

If you *really* want to do what you are doing...

```
class Test(object):
    def __new__(*args):
        return False
```